# How to resolve subselections / relations in prisma (nested lists)

Tags: graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

Let's take an example from the github repo of prisma:

We have a user, the user could have multiple posts, and one post could have multiple links.

My goal is, to retrieve all posts and all links.
This means, my response is a list (links) in a list (posts).

I want to map the values I get back as two nested lists.

**datamodel.prisma**

```js
type User {
  id: ID! @id
  email: String! @unique
  name: String
  posts: [Post]!
}

type Post {
  id: ID! @id
  createdAt: DateTime! @createdAt
  updatedAt: DateTime! @updatedAt
  published: Boolean! @default(value: false)
  title: String!
  content: String
  author: User!
  links: [Link]!
}

type Link {
  id: ID! @id
  url: String
  title: String
  post: Post!
}
```

**schema.graphql**

```js
type Query {
  ...
}

type Mutation {
  ...
}

type Link {
  id: ID!
  url: String
  title: String
  post: Post!
}

type Post {
  id: ID!
  createdAt: DateTime!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  published: Boolean!
  title: String!
  content: String
  author: User!
}

type User {
  id: ID!
  email: String!
  name: String
  posts: [Post]!
}
```

I want to query **all posts** of a user, and all of the links for every post in the response.

How would I query this request?

```
user {
  id
  posts {
    id
    links {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

The above code snipper would not work.

**EDIT**
I want to use the following:

```js
User: {
  listPosts: (parent, args, context, info) {
    return context.prisma.posts().links()
  }
}
```

So in my response (data in front-end via react-apollo Query Component), I want to map over posts AND the links in each post.

BUT the links attribute in posts is null.

Is there another way to achieve this?!

Comment: @DanielRearden Prisma defaults to an inline relation, so in this case, this is not necessary.

Comment: Can you clarify what's not working? What errors are you seeing? How are you actually using the above query inside your resolver?

Comment: @DanielRearden updated my question. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs:

> Prisma client has a fluent API to query relations in your database. Meaning you can simply chain your method calls to navigate the relation properties of the returned records. **This is only possible when retrieving single records, not for lists. Meaning you can not query relation fields of records that are returned in a list.**

In order to get around that limitation, you can use the `$fragment` method:

```
const fragment = `
fragment UserWithPostsAndLinks on User {
  id
  email
  name
  posts {
    id
    title
    content
    links {
      id
      url
      title
    }
  }
}
`

const userWithPostsAndLinks = await prisma.user({ id: args.id }).$fragment(fragment)
```